# TypeScript: Реализовать обобщённую функцию, которая принимает тип перечисления и значения этого перечисления

Tags: typescript, generics, enum

Существует ли способ реализовать обобщённую функцию, которая принимает только значения конкретного перечисления?:

```
type EnumType = { [i: string]: string|number }

function f <T extends EnumType> (value: /* value of T only */) {
  // ...
}
```

Допустим есть такие перечисления:

```
enum Color {
  Red = 'red',
  Blue = 'blue'
}

enum DayOfWeek {
  Sunday = 0,
  Monday = 1,
  // ...
}
```

После чего вызовы функции должны быть типобезопасными:

```
f<Color>(Color.Red) // Можно
f<Color>('sdf') // Компилятор говорит "нельзя"
f<Color>('red') // Тоже лучше не разрешать, хотя значение из Color
f<Color>(DayOfWeek.Sunday) // Нельзя.
```

Пробовал `value: keyof T` , но это работает не так как я хотел:

```
// Пример, когда  value: keyof T
f<Color>(Color.Red) // Нельзя
f<Color>('Red') // Можно, но 'Red' - это имя значения, а не само значение
```

Мне нужно передавать именно Значения перечисления, а не их имена!
Также не помогло `value: T`, ибо так можно передавать само перечисление, а не отдельные его значения.

Как быть?

В результате должен получиться реакт компонент, с такими пропсами:

- enum: Перечисление
- value: Значение_перечисления
- onChange: (value: Значение_перечисления) => void

Это делается для того, чтобы

- при замене перечисления не приходилось менять сами компоненты;
- значения были не string|number, а к примеру Color

Comment: `'red'` - это строка, а не значение `enum`

Comment: Вот по этому я и хочу, чтоб компилятор на него тоже ругался.

Comment: тогда чем тебя не устроило `value: T`?

Comment: @Grundy Я щас чекнул, на числах ошибка не работает (обновил ответ)

Comment: @EzioMercer, да :) вот такие вот enum а тайпскрипте :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) сказано так:

```
enum Color {
  Red = 'red',
  Blue = 'blue'
}

function f <T> (value: T) {
  console.log(value);
}

f<Color>(Color.Red); // OK
f<Color>('red'); // Error
```

##### UPD

Это не работает для чисел

```
enum DayOfWeek {
  Sunday = 0,
  Monday = 1
}

function f <T> (value: T) {
  console.log(value);
}

f<DayOfWeek>(DayOfWeek.Sunday); // OK
f<DayOfWeek>(0); // OK
f<DayOfWeek>(2); // OK
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только что запилил компонент и теперь у меня один Select на все Enum-ы) Да, ты прав, документацию таки надо читать:)